# ambiguous call of overloaded template with parameter (const T&, const T&) or (const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M])

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

For the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

template <typename T>
int compare(const T&, const T&) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    return 0;
}
template <size_t N, size_t M>
int compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M]) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    compare("hi", "is");
}
```

When I compiles the code with `g++ -std=c++1y`, it complains:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘compare(const char [3], const char [3])’ is ambiguous
     compare("hi", "is");
```

According to the rules of template overloading, viable functions are:

```
compare(const T&, const T&) with T = char [3]
compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M]) with N = 3ul, M = 3ul
```

They both provide an equally good (i.e., exact) match to the call. So I should check which one is more specialized.

But according to my limited knowledge, `const T&` is more general than `const char (&)[N]`. So I think that `compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[M])` is more specialized. But why is this call ambiguous?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first overload `compare(const T&, const T&)` forces both parameters to be the same type, while the second overload doesn't. So in this regard the first overload is more specific.

However, the second overload forces both parameters to be `char` arrays, so it is more specific in that regard.

Therefore, neither overload can be said to be more specialized than the other, and the result is the ambiguity error.

Another way to look at it is that each overload can accept an input that the other doesn't: Only the first overload will accept a call where both arguments are `int&`. And only the second overload will accept a call where the arguments are `char (&)[2]` and `char (&)[3]`.

If you change the second overload to

```
template <size_t N> int compare(const char (&)[N], const char (&)[N])
```

it will fix the error, as this is now strictly more specific than the first overload.

Comment: I agree on the explanation, but the solution limits the use of the second `compare` to equal-sized strings.

Comment: Thank you. I may have understood the meaning of the word "specialized." But what is the exact rule of "specialized" in C++? I have not read the specification of C++. And I am reading the book C++ Primer.

Comment: @xtofl It was one example for a way to fix the error. Another example would be changing the first overload to take two different types. Without knowing the requirements I can't give a solution that satisfies them.

Comment: @zhenguoli Informally, A is at least as specialized as B if every way to call A is also a valid way to call B. Above I showed that this isn't the case here because there are ways to call each overload that won't work with the other.

Comment: That is, A is more specialized than B is equivalent to *the ways to call A is a subset of the ways to call B*. Does that make sense?

Comment: @zhen That is a decent rule of thumb.  But the exaxt definition is going ti involve standardese and some corner cases.  It is impoetant to understand it is a partial order.